# woocommerce - check if cart cointains 2 specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

currently i can check if the cart contains categories (or a specific category) with this function..

```
function check_the_cart_for_categories() {

// holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category
$category_checks = array();
    
// check each cart item for our category
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        
$product = $cart_item['data'];
$product_in_cat = false;

if ( has_term( array('clothing', 'shoes','hats'), 'product_cat', $product->id )  )  {
#if ( has_term( 'clothing', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) { //or for one
     $product_in_cat = true;
}

array_push( $category_checks, $product_in_cat );

}
 
// if all items are in this category, do something
if ( ! in_array( false, $category_checks, true ) AND $ship_check ) {
echo "showmessage";     
}
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' , 'check_the_cart_for_categories');
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit' , 'check_the_cart_for_categories');
```

but i want to check if the cart contains SHOES and HATS! (not any of them) ?
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be done but need to do fix some bugs. check my below code.

```
function check_the_cart_for_categories() {

    // holds checks for all products in cart to see if they're in our category
    $product_in_cat = false;
        
    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        if ( has_term( 'shoes', 'product_cat', $product_id ) && has_term( 'hats', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
             $product_in_cat = true;
        }

        break;

    }
     
    // if all items are in this category, do something
    if ( $product_in_cat ) {
        echo "showmessage";     
    }
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'check_the_cart_for_categories' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'check_the_cart_for_categories' );
```

UPDATE as per OP request. ( check both categories in cart )

```
function check_the_cart_for_categories() {
     
    // Categories in a coma separated array
    $must_categories = array('shoes','hats');
    $fee_amount = 0;

    $product_cat = array();

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
           $product_cat[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $must_categories as $key => $must_cat ) {
        
        if( in_array($must_cat, $product_cat) ){
            $product_in_cat = true;
        }else{
            $product_in_cat = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    // if all items are in this category, do something
    if ( $product_in_cat ) {
        echo "showmessage";     
    }
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'check_the_cart_for_categories' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'check_the_cart_for_categories' );
```

Comment: hello. with this function it checks if the cart contain "shoes" or "hats"... not "shoes" AND "hats"! ?